# "Case_when" depending on the index of an element in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, vectorization

Vectorized operations tend to work so that a logic is applied to EVERY element of a vector.

However, let's assume I have a vector i.e.

```
> 1:10
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I would like to apply a function, say, multiplication by 0.5 to every element except the first and the last element: I would like to multiply them by 0.3.

Is there a dplyr (or any other vectorized) way to do this?

I know that sapply with if-else structure would do the trick i.e.

```
sapply(seq(1:10), #I know seq() is not actually needed in this particular case
    function(i) {
        if(i == 1 | i == length(1:10)) {
            (1:10)[i]*0.3
        } else {
            (1:10)[i]*0.5
        }
    }
)
```

...but vectorized solution with an index dependent case_when would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you explicitly mentioned `case_when` in your title, one index dependent `case_when` solution could be:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- 1:10

data.frame(x) %>%
  mutate(x_mult = case_when(
    row_number() == 1 | row_number() == n() ~ x * 3,
    TRUE ~ x * 5
  ))
```

Output:

```
    x x_mult
1   1      3
2   2     10
3   3     15
4   4     20
5   5     25
6   6     30
7   7     35
8   8     40
9   9     45
10 10     30
```

Answer (score 2):

`ifelse` is vectorized, so you can use

```
x <- 1:10
x * ifelse(seq_along(x) %in% c(1, length(x)), 0.3, 0.5)
#[1] 0.3 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 3.0
```

---

This is another one with same logic but without `ifelse`.

```
x * c(0.5, 0.3)[seq_along(x) %in% c(1, length(x)) + 1]
```

where `seq_along(x) %in% c(1, length(x)) + 1` creates an index (either 1 or 2) and is used to subset the vector `c(0.5, 0.3)` which is multiplied by `x`. However, using `ifelse` is less confusing in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

So as I see you want to replace the first and last element by the value multiplied by 0.3, otherwise multiplied by 0.5.

You could do it imperatively by:

```
x <- 1:10
x[ x == 1 | x == length(x)] <- 0.3 * x[1]
x <- 0.5 * x
```

As a function:

```
modify_by_factors <- function(vec, first_last_k=0.3, other_k=0.5) {
  # multiply by other_k all values by vectorization
  res <- vec * other_k
  
  # overwrite first and last value
  res[1] <- vec[1] * first_last_k
  res[length(vec)] <- vec[length(vec)] * first_last_k

  # return result vector
  res
}
```

With this function, you can change 0.3 and 0.5 as factors to different values.

speed-wise this might be the faster solution than using `ifelse` or `mutate` or any of the `apply` functions.

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
library(magrittr)

foo <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  x[ c(1,n)] %<>% multiply_by(0.3)
  x[-c(1,n)] %<>% multiply_by(0.5)
  x
}

foo(1:10)
# [1] 0.3 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0 3.5 4.0 4.5 3.0
```